# Using `with_scope` in Locomotive CMS

Tags: locomotivecms, wagon

###I have a question regarding the use of `with_scope` in Locomotive CMS.

To start I have a model, `movies`, with full fields, one of which is called `film_etats` with `type: belongs_to`.

I have another model, `film_etats`, where I have an `etat` field which is of `type: string` and another field `movies` with `type: has_many`.

This works okay - I get to see my data - but what I would like to do is to filter the information.

In the Locomotive CMS docs I find this:
https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/tags#with_scope

#### Here the first example.

```
{% with_scope author: 'John Doe' %}
    {% for post in content_type.posts %}
        {{ post.title }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith_scope %}
```

So I did this:

```
{% with_scope film_etats.etat: 'Production' %}
    {% for film in contents.film %}
        etat du film : {{film.film_etats.etat}}
    {% endfor %}
{% endwith_scope %}
```

but it does not work and what I want but a type error: undefined method `entries' for nil: NilClass

### my model films

```
title_film => type (string)
film_etats => type belongs_to
```

### my model film_etats

```
etat => type(string)
films => type(has_many)
```

thanks

Comment: `{% for film in contents.film %}` should be `{% for film in contents.films %}` - it's important to [use the plural in content_types](https://doc.locomotivecms.com/docs/define-a-content-type).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your code is a little strange, because if it worked, all it would do is print out a list of the word "Production" many times. i.e.

```
etat du film : Production
etat du film : Production
etat du film : Production
....
```

The reason it's not working is that you can't use `with_scope` to filter based on a related model's field. The following code will print the title of all films in production.

```
{% with_scope etat: 'Production' %}
    {% assign production = contents.film_etats.first %}
{% endwith_scope %}

Production Films:<br />
{% for film in production.films %}
    - {{ film.title_film }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```